# Generating a CSR using Certtools in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnutls

I've generated many CSR's using OpenSSL.  It's easy and straight forward.   However, GnuTLS is the new and updated replacement for SSL on Ubuntu according to some sources but the interrogation during creation of the CSR is a bit more complex.

To generate a CSR for use in ubuntu 18.04 for the environment described above, you use Certtools.  Certtools is the GnuTLS CSR creation tool that must be installed separately from GnuTLS itself.  Note that if you generate a CSR using OpenSSL, it may not work.  That's the problem I encountered.   Apparently, if you install GnuTLS in place of OpenSSL, you need to generate your CSR and any other necessary documents with Certtools.

When you invoke the Certtools GENERATE CSR process, some of the questions are standard and easy to answer.  Others, I have no idea how to answer or if they are optional or required.  ***I've marked what I consider to be the more difficult to answer questions with a dash - and ask that an expert with this give an answer or explanation to those marked in the CODE section below as to whether the item is optional or required, and an easier to understand example and or explanation of what is being asked for might be.***

Note that I have indeed gone to the GnuTLS web site and read all available documentation, however, as a beginner to GnuTLS, I didn't find the documentation beginner friendly.   Perhaps at some point someone will write a simpler to understand, clarified version for those not fully educated in CSR creation matters. [GnuTLS Certtool Documentation](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/certtool-Invocation.html)

That said, when you go to generate a CSR using Certtools, here is the barrage of questions you will be faced with....

```
**Generating a PKCS #10 certificate request...**
Common name: 
Organizational unit name:             
Organization name: 
Locality name: 
State or province name: 
Country name (2 chars): 
-Enter the subject's domain component (DC): 
-Enter the subject's domain component (DC): 
-UID: 
-Enter a dnsName of the subject of the certificate: 
-Enter a URI of the subject of the certificate: 
Enter the IP address of the subject of the certificate: 
Enter the e-mail of the subject of the certificate: 
Enter a challenge password: 
Does the certificate belong to an authority? (y/N): 
-Path length constraint (decimal, -1 for no constraint): 
-Will the certificate be used for signing (DHE ciphersuites)? (Y/n): 
Will the certificate be used for encryption (RSA ciphersuites)? (Y/n): 
-Will the certificate be used to sign code? (y/N): 
-Will the certificate be used for time stamping? (y/N): 
-Will the certificate be used for email protection? (y/N): 
-Will the certificate be used for IPsec IKE operations? (y/N): 
-Will the certificate be used to sign OCSP requests? (y/N): 
-Will the certificate be used to sign other certificates? (y/N): 
-Will the certificate be used to sign CRLs? (y/N): 
-Is this a TLS web client certificate? (y/N): 
-Is this a TLS web server certificate? (y/N):
```

Thank you and I hope this helps others in trying to set up GnuTLS SSL SNI certificates

Another excellent source of information on this topic
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuTLS

Comment: "So, if for example, your server has 5 virtual hosts, but you only have one IP address, you cannot use OpenSSL for that." I'm not completely sure (therefore writing a comment instead of an answer), but as far as I know you can use SNI with OpenSSL just fine. Just create CSRs for your domains, hand them to your CA to sign them, and install the certificates the CA sends you back. If your server (Apache, NGINX or whatever you're using) supports SNI, it should look for a certificate for the hostname of the respective virtual host.

Comment: Thanks.The amount of information can become overwhelming.  Not sure why I thought OpenSSL could not utilize SNI (or where I read it) .  Apparently it can. So now I'm siting here trying to recall why I went with GnuTLS to begin with.  For a beginner, all of this can make your head swim.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "--template" option while generating a CSR.
Template file would contain pre-filled answers. certtool will consider this file and select default values for all other parameters which are not mentioned in this template file.

Sample template file:

```
$ cat client.info
organization = MYORG
cn = client
tls_www_client
encryption_key
signing_key
```